# $f$ is differentiable with $Df(a)$ not a isomorphism, then $f^{-1}$ is not invertible at $f(a)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ a bijective $C^1$ function, and let $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Df(a)$ is not a isomorphism. Then $f^{-1}$ is not invertible at $f(a)$.

Comment: What does "$f^{-1}$ is not invertible at $f(a)$" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a proof of this fact.

This is a different formulation of one side of the inverse function theorem, which states that a $C^1$ function is a local diffeomorphism at a point *if and only if* its Jacobian is not zero at that point. The proof relies on Banach's theorem on contraction on complete metric spaces and is not complicated, rather it's long. You can find it in any analysis textbook, for instance Rudin's.